# Closed Form for an Expression Involving the Smallest Triangular Number Not Exceeding a Given Integer

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, triangular-numbers

Let $n \geq 1$ be an integer. Recall that a number $t$ is *triangular* if there exists an integer $r \geq 0$ such that $t = \binom{r + 1} 2,$ where we take $\binom 1 2 = 0$ by convention.

It appears to me that the following statement is true.

> **Claim.** If $t = \binom{r + 1} 2$ is the smallest triangular number such that $n \leq t,$ then $$r = \sqrt{2t + \frac 1 4} - \frac 1 2 = {\left \lceil \sqrt{2n + \frac 1 4} - \frac 1 2 \right \rceil}.$$

One can verify the first equality by $t = \dfrac{r(r + 1)} 2$; yet, the second equality stumps me.

I would appreciate any comment or advice. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Similar to how $\lceil\sqrt n\rceil$ will take on the same integer value for several consecutive values of $n$, the equalities above have the same values $r,t$ repeated for some count of consecutive values of $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(n) = \sqrt{2n + \frac14} -\frac12$.

The equation $r = \sqrt{2t + \frac 1 4} - \frac 1 2$ for $t = \binom{r+1}{2}$ tells us that $f(\binom{r+1}{2}) = r$. Similarly, we know that $f(\binom r2) = r-1$.

Also, $f(n)$ is an increasing function of $n$. Therefore for $\binom r2 < n \le \binom{r+1}{2}$, we have $r-1 < f(n) \le r$. But this is exactly what we need to know to conclude that $\lceil f(n) \rceil = r$.

To recap: if $\binom r2 < n \le \binom{r+1}{2}$ (in other words, if $r$ is the least value such that $n \le \binom{r+1}{2}$), then $\left\lceil\sqrt{2n + \frac14} -\frac12 \right\rceil = r$.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much! It was much simpler than I had envisioned.